# Compact generators of $\mathcal{D}\text{-Mod}$ via Mayer Vietoris

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, d-modules

Let $X$ be a complex variety (or any space for whom a category of sheaves with the six functors is defined), and
$$i\ :\ Z\ \to\ X\ \leftarrow\ U\ :\ j$$
be complementary open and closed embeddings.

It is useful to find a compact generator $c_X$ for $\mathcal{D}\text{-Mod}(X)$, because then this category is just $\text{End}(c_X)$.

**Question:** if $c_Z$ and $c_U$ are compact generators for the category of D modules on $Z$ and $U$, can we form a compact generator $c_X$ using them? e.g. $c_X=j_!c_U\oplus i_*c_Z$.

As far as I can tell, you cannot prove that any of the obvious candidates for $c_X$ compactly generate by abstract six functor nonsense. If that is indeed the case, I'd be more interested in positive answers that are conditional on the geometry of the spaces.

Comment: The sum of the pushforwards should generate, by general nonsense applied to the key triangle $j_!j^*F -> F -> i_*i^*F$.. What's not general is that the pushforwards are compact, which is true here but not for q-c sheaves. The formal property you need is that $j^*j_! F$ generates the same subcategory as $F$, and the same for $i^*i_*$. In fact, both are identity functors.

Comment: "which is true here but not for q-c sheaves" - this is the content of my question, so if you know an answer you should post it.